# Listing duplicated records using T SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a database that is used to record patient information for a small clinic. We use MS SQL Server 2008 as the backend. The patient table contains the following columns:

```
Id int identity(1,1), 
FamilyName varchar(30),
FirstName varchar (20), 
DOB datetime, 
AddressLine1 varchar (50), 
AddressLine2 varchar (50), 
State varchar (20), 
Postcode varchar (4), 
NextOfKin varchar (20), 
Homephone varchar (20), 
Mobile varchar (20)
```

Occasionally the staff register a new patient, unaware that the patient already has a record in the system. We end up with several thousands duplicated records.

What I would like to do is to present a list of patients who have duplicated records for the staff to merge during quiet time. We consider 2 records to be duplicated if the 2 records have exactly the same FamilyName, FirstName and DOB. What I am doing at the moment is to use a sub query to return the records as follow:

```
SELECT FamilyName, 
       FirstName, 
       DOB, 
       AddressLine1, 
       AddressLine2, 
       State, 
       Postcode, 
       NextOfKin, 
       HomePhone,
       Mobile 
FROM
Patients AS p1 
WHERE Id IN 
          ( 
            SELECT Max(Id) 
            FROM Patients AS p2, 
            COUNT(id) AS NumberOfDuplicate 
            GROUP BY    
            FamilyName, 
            FirstName, 
            DOB HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
          )
```

This produces the result but the performance is terrible. Is there any better way to do it? The only requirements is I need to show all the fields in the Patients table as the user of the system wants to view all the details before making the decision whether to merge the records or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will output every row which has a duplicate, based on firstname and lastname

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM Table AS t1 
    INNER JOIN Table AS t2
    ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname 
       AND t1.lastname = t2.lastname
       AND t1.id <> t2.id
```

Comment: Wow that is an elegant solution. I never thought about doing it this way

Comment: Thanks I ended up using your solution rather than the CTE one as the join statement seems to deliver better performance. How do I accept your solution please?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build an index on the 3 fields you use to detect duplicates,
then try this query:

```
with Duplicates as
( 
    select FamilyName, FirstName, DOB
    from Patients 
    group by FamilyName, FirstName, DOB
    having count(*) > 1 
)
Select Patients.* 
from Patients 
    inner join Duplicates
    on Patients.FamilyName = Duplicates.FamilyName 
       And Patients.FirstName= Duplicates.FirstName
       and Patients.DOB= Duplicates.DOB
```

Comment: This will list all rows for each duplicate

Comment: Thanks. I already have a composite index on those 3 fields. Will try the CTE as you suggested tomorrow when I am back at work. Just wondering other from being a lot more readable, does it mean in term of performance CTE is better than subquery?

Comment: Thanks, your solution works but I ended up using the Join approach as somehow CTE is slightly slower than JOin. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I'd do following:

1. add indexes to FamilyName, FirstName and DOB
2. create view for your subquery
3. modified the query as following

   `Select p.* FROM Patients p INNER JOIN view_name v ON v.FirstName=p.Firstname AND ...`

Comment: That's actually the next step I plan to do since hopping that prebuilt SQL views would have some source of statistics that would improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT Id, FamilyName, FirstName ,DOB
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FamilyName, FirstName ,DOB ORDER BY Id) AS DuplicateCount
FROM PatientTable
)
select * from CTE where DuplicateCount > 1
```

Comment: How is this better?  Not saying it isn't, but you should explain.

Comment: @itsbruce For start OP query will throw error , Second your question covers a lot of ground so simply telling which will be better is not correct, However one can compare their execution plans.But if you can shed some light into this matter please do.

Comment: @itsbruce However i would like to know about your comment, How is my query better ?BTW thanks for raising a good question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select FamilyName, FirstName, DOB 
   from Patients 
  group by FamilyName, FirstName, DOB 
 having count(*)>1
```

Will show all duplicates.

However, please consider names being written different, but similar. You might want to look for the topics 'data deduplication' and/or 'record linkage'. I solved the problem using a string similarity algorithm (modified Jaro/Winkler and levenshtein).